# Cannot convert object to object* in initialization?

Tags: c++, object, linked-list

I am trying to write a function that will insert a new node in to my linked list. I have defined that function as:

```
template <typename T>
void InsertNode(node<T>* front, const T & value)
{
node<T>* newNode = CreateNode(value);

// if the list is empty or if insert in front of front  
if (front == NULL || front->nodeValue >= newNode->nodeValue) {
    newNode->next = front;
    front = newNode;
}
else
{
     //Locate the node before the point of insertion 

    node<T>* curr = front;
    while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->nodeValue < newNode->nodeValue)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    newNode->next = curr->next;
    curr->next = newNode;
}
```

}

I call this function with:

```
InsertNode(first, c);
```

Definition of `CreateNode`:

```
template <typename T>
node<T> CreateNode(const T & value)
{
    return new node<T>(value);
}
```

I am getting an error that states (when compiling with g++):

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void InsertNode(node<T>*, const T&) [with T = Course]’:
main.cpp:143:23:   required from here
main.cpp:248:37: error: cannot convert ‘node<Course>’ to ‘node<Course>*’ in initialization
  node<T>* newNode = CreateNode(value);
                                     ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘node<T> CreateNode(const T&) [with T = Course]’:
main.cpp:248:31:   required from ‘void InsertNode(node<T>*, const T&) [with T = Course]’
main.cpp:143:23:   required from here
main.cpp:304:26: error: could not convert ‘(operator new(112ul), (<statement>, ((node<Course>*)<anonymous>)))’ from ‘node<Course>*’ to ‘node<Course>’
  return new node<T>(value);
```

What is causing this error? I have not been able to figure it out. If more code is needed such as the prototypes or anything else, let me know. 
If someone could help with the formatting that would be great.

Comment: What's the definition of `CreateNode`?

Comment: *" If more code is needed such as the prototypes or anything else, let me know..."* - Yes please, a little more code that satisfies [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like you need `void InsertNode(node<T>*& front, const T & value)`

Comment: I got it to compile by changing it to `void InsertNode(node<T>*& front, const T & value)` but I now get: /tmp/ccOTcKNo.o: In function main:
main.cpp:(.text+0x972): undefined reference to `void InsertNode<Course>(node<Course>*, Course const&)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` when I link it.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message carefully:

```
main.cpp:248:37: error: cannot convert ‘node<Course>’ to ‘node<Course>*’ in initialization
node<T>* newNode = CreateNode(value);
                                     ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘node<T> CreateNode(const T&) [with T = Course]’:
```

Clearly, your `CreateNode` is returning an actual object `node<T>`, but you are assigning it to `node<T>*`.

Most likely you want your `CreateNode` acting as a more sophisticated `new`, returning an object on the heap, i.e. `node<T>*`. If that is the case -- change it accordingly. I would rename it though as `newNode` or something with `new` at the beginning, giving a hint to the user, that at some point, someone should `delete` it.

If you cannot change the signature of `CreateNode` you need to make a copy of the node you obtain:

```
Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(CreateNode(value))
```

I must stress however, that this may be inefficient if `Node<T>` is big -- you make a copy here, and then discard the original. Unless, of course, `Node<T>` has a r-value reference copy constructor, but that is another story...

---

After the question was edited I notice:

```
template <typename T>
node<T> CreateNode(const T & value)
{
    return new node<T>(value);
}
```

This shouldn't compile either! `new node<T>(...)` has a pointer type `node<T>*` but your function is returning an actual object `node<T>`. Just change the signature to return the pointer -- it should fix both this error and the error you stated in your question.

Comment: I was given the declaration of `CreateNode` and `InsertNode` so I'm not sure what I should do, sorry new to linked lists here.

Comment: Just noticed that as you replied too, fixed my compilation error but still getting the linking error as stated in the comments above

Comment: Then talk to whoever gave you the declaration. It is either an error of theirs, or they expect something different from you. Either way, this is beyond the scope of SO.